# Issue with Livewire and Bootstrap Modal Form Submission after Pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am currently working on a Laravel Livewire project where I have a page displaying a table. The table is populated with data fetched from the server using Livewire. Each row in the table has an associated "Edit" button, which triggers a Bootstrap modal containing a form.

The issue arises after paginating through the table. On the initial page, the modal form submission works perfectly, but after navigating to subsequent pages, the form fails to submit.

I tried to convert the submission through livewire also face same problem. I suspect that the Livewire state might not persist after pagination, causing issues with the modal form submission. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is a code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Item;
use App\Models\Branch;
use App\Models\Car;
use App\Models\Employee;
use App\Models\User;

use App\Models\PurchasedItem;
use App\Models\Utils;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Purchased extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $start_date;
    public $end_date;
    public $branch;
    public $driver;
    public $storeman;
    public $receipt;

    public $branches;
    public $items;
    public $cars;
    public $employees;
    public $users;
    public $utils;
    public $storemans;

    protected $purchased_items;
    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    public function render()
    {
        $this->items = Item::all();
        $this->branches = Branch::all();
        $this->cars = Car::all();
        $this->employees = Employee::all();
        $this->users = User::all();
        $this->utils = new Utils;
        $this->storemans = User::where('role', 2)->get();

        $pur_item = PurchasedItem::query();

        if (!empty($this->branch)) {
            $pur_item = $pur_item->where('branch_id', '=', $this->branch);
        }
        if (!empty($this->start_date)) {
            $pur_item = $pur_item->where('date', '>=', $this->start_date);
        }
        if (!empty($this->end_date)) {
            $pur_item = $pur_item->where('date', '<=', $this->end_date);
        }
        if (!empty($this->receipt)) {
            $pur_item = $pur_item->where('receipt', 'like', '%' . $this->receipt . '%');
        }
        if (!empty($this->storeman)) {
            $pur_item = $pur_item->where('storeman_id', '=', $this->storeman);
        }
        if (!empty($this->driver)) {
            $pur_item = $pur_item->where('driver_id', '=', $this->driver);
        }

        $pur_item = $pur_item->orderBy('receipt', 'asc')->get();

        $grouped_items = $pur_item->groupBy('receipt');

        $paginated_groups = $grouped_items->slice(($this->page - 1) * 10, 10)->all();
        $total_groups = count($grouped_items);
        $this->purchased_items = new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $paginated_groups,
            $total_groups,
            10,
            $this->page,
            ['path' => request()->url()]
        );

        return view('livewire.purchased')->extends('layout.managerlayout', [
            'items' => $this->items, 'branches' => $this->branches, 'storemans' => $this->storemans
        ]);
    }

    public function getPurchasedItems()
    {
        return $this->purchased_items;
    }

    public function updated()
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }
}
```

Blade File

```
<div>
    @php
        $purchased_items = $this->getPurchasedItems();
    @endphp

    @foreach ($purchased_items as $receipt => $grouped_item)
        <div class="modal fade" id="purchaseModal{{ $receipt }}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title text-bold" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Purchase Transaction</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <form method="post" action="{{ route('manager.update_purchased_item') }}">
                            @csrf
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $receipt }}">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Storeman<a style="color:red;">*</a></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="storeman_id" required="">
                                        <option value="{{ $grouped_item->first()->storeman_id }}">
                                            {{ $users->find($grouped_item->first()->storeman_id)->name }}</option>
                                        @foreach ($users->where('role', 'storeman') as $storeman)
                                            <option value="{{ $storeman->id }}">
                                                {{ $storeman->name }}
                                            </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Branch<a style="color:red;">*</a></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="branch_id" required="">
                                        <option value="{{ $grouped_item->first()->branch_id }}">
                                            {{ $branches->find($grouped_item->first()->branch_id)->name }}</option>
                                        @foreach ($branches as $branche)
                                            <option value="{{ $branche->id }}">
                                                {{ $branche->name }}
                                            </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Car<a style="color:red;">*</a></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="car_id" required="">
                                        <option value="{{ $grouped_item->first()->car_id }}">
                                            {{ $cars->find($grouped_item->first()->car_id)->plate_no }}</option>
                                        @foreach ($cars as $car)
                                            <option value="{{ $car->id }}">
                                                {{ $car->plate_no }}
                                            </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Driver<a style="color:red;">*</a></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="driver_id" required="">
                                        <option value="{{ $grouped_item->first()->driver_id }}">
                                            {{ $employees->find($grouped_item->first()->driver_id)->name }}
                                        </option>
                                        @foreach ($employees as $driver)
                                            <option value="{{ $driver->id }}">
                                                {{ $driver->name }}
                                            </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Type<a style="color:red;">*</a></label>
                                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="type" required="">
                                        <option value="{{ $grouped_item->first()->type }}">
                                            {{ $grouped_item->first()->type }}</option>
                                        <option value="Bonus">Bonus</option>
                                        <option value="Purchased">Purchased</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Transaction Date<a style="color:red;">*</a></label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="date"
                                        placeholder="Enter Date" required=""
                                        value="{{ $grouped_item->first()->date }}">
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Transaction Receipt No<a
                                            style="color:red;">*</a></label>

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="receipt"
                                        placeholder="Enter Receipt No" required="" value="{{ $receipt }}">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Load Date</label>
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="load_date"
                                        placeholder="Enter Date" value="{{ $grouped_item->first()->load_date }}">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Load Receipt No</label>

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="load_receipt"
                                        placeholder="Enter Receipt No"
                                        value="{{ $grouped_item->first()->load_receipt }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <hr>

                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <th class="col-5">Item</th>
                                    <th class="col-2">Quantity</th>
                                    <th class="col-3">Expiration Date</th>
                                    <th class="col-2">Unit Price</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="purchased_repeatable_body">
                                    @foreach ($grouped_item as $gitem)
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="{{ $gitem->id }}">
                                        <tr id="purchased_repeatable_form">
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="item_id[]"
                                                        required="">
                                                        <option value="{{ $gitem->item_id }}">
                                                            {{ $items->find($gitem->item_id)->name }}</option>
                                                        @foreach ($items as $item)
                                                            <option value="{{ $item->id }}">
                                                                {{ $item->name }}
                                                            </option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                                        name="ammount[]" placeholder="Enter Name" required=""
                                                        value="{{ $gitem->ammount }}">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                                        name="expiration_date[]" placeholder="Enter Expiration Date"
                                                        required="" value="{{ $gitem->expiration_date }}">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                                        name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price" required=""
                                                        value="{{ $gitem->price }}">
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <hr>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Remark<a style="color:red;">*</a></label>

                                    <textarea name="remark" rows="6" class="form-control form-control-sm">{{ $grouped_item->first()->remark }}</textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
                    </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach

    <div class="card-header bg-success m-0 p-2" id="headingFive">
        <strong class="card-title float-left m-0 p-0">Purchase transactions</strong>
        <div class="float-right row mb-1">
            From : <input wire:model="start_date" type="date" class="col form-control form-control-sm mx-1"> To :
            <input wire:model="end_date" type="date" class="col form-control form-control-sm mx-1">

            <input wire:model.lazy="receipt" type="search" class="col form-control form-control-sm mx-1"
                placeholder="Receipt No">

            <select wire:model="storeman" class="col form-control form-control-sm mx-1">
                <option value="">{{ __('Select Storeman') }}</option>
                @foreach ($storemans as $storeman)
                    <option value="{{ $storeman->id }}">{{ $storeman->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

            <select wire:model="driver" class="col form-control form-control-sm mx-1">
                <option value="">{{ __('Select Driver') }}</option>
                @foreach ($employees as $employee)
                    <option value="{{ $employee->id }}">{{ $employee->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

            <select wire:model="branch" class="col form-control form-control-sm mx-1">
                <option value="">{{ __('Select Branch') }}</option>
                @foreach ($branches as $branch)
                    <option value="{{ $branch->id }}">{{ $branch->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body m-0 p-0">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table " style="max-height: 420px">
                <thead class="bg-success sticky-top top-0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Transaction Date</th>
                        <th>Transaction Receipt</th>
                        <th>Branch</th>
                        <th>Storeman</th>
                        <th>Car</th>
                        <th>Driver</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>L. Receipt</th>
                        <th>L. Date</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($purchased_items as $receipt => $grouped_item)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $grouped_item->first()->date }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $receipt }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $branches->find($grouped_item->first()->branch_id)->name }}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ $users->find($grouped_item->first()->storeman_id)->name }}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ $cars->find($grouped_item->first()->car_id)->plate_no }}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ $employees->find($grouped_item->first()->driver_id)->name }}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ $grouped_item->first()->type }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $grouped_item->first()->load_receipt }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $grouped_item->first()->load_date }}</td>

                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                        data-target="#PurchaseCollapse{{ $grouped_item->first()->id }}"
                                        aria-expanded="false"
                                        aria-controls="PurchaseCollapse{{ $grouped_item->first()->id }}">
                                        More
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning mx-1" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#purchaseModal{{ $receipt }}">
                                        Edit
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs p-0 m-0">
                                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs p-0 m-0"
                                            href='{{ route('manager.delete_transaction', [$receipt, 'purchase', 'multi']) }}'>Delete</a>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        <tr class="collapse" id="PurchaseCollapse{{ $grouped_item->first()->id }}">
                            <td colspan="10">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
                                        <thead>
                                            <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th>Item</th>
                                            <th>Quantity</th>
                                            <th>Exp. Date</th>
                                            <th>Unit Price</th>
                                            <th>Total Price</th>
                                            <th class="col-6">Remark</th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            @foreach ($grouped_item as $no => $sitem)
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>{{ $loop->iteration }} </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a class="btn btn-link btn-xs text-danger"
                                                            href='{{ route('manager.delete_transaction', [$sitem->id, 'purchase', 'single']) }}'>Delete</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>{{ $items->find($sitem->item_id)->name }}</td>
                                                    <td>{{ $sitem->ammount }}</td>
                                                    <td>{{ $sitem->expiration_date }}</td>
                                                    <td>{{ $sitem->price }}</td>
                                                    <td>{{ $sitem->ammount * $sitem->price }}</td>

                                                    @if ($loop->iteration == 1)
                                                        <td rowspan="{{ count($grouped_item) }}" align="justify">
                                                            {{ $sitem->remark }}
                                                        </td>
                                                    @endif
                                                </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {{ $purchased_items->links() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code, it's not possible to formulate a solution from your description

Comment: I can't understand why you are manually manipulating and paginating the recovered data. I point the finger at this section. Also you didn't publish the Blade view.

Comment: Manual manipulation of the recovered data was necessary because, in Laravel, pagination is not directly supported after grouping the data.